# Excel application running in background when using Solver Add-in

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, excel-addins, vba

I'm developing a .NET application that opens a workbook, runs some VBA macros, refresh connections, etc. It's fine, but when I run some VBA macro that uses functions of Solver Add-in an Excel instance keep running even after I realeased all COM objects correctly (calling 'Marshal.ReleaseComObject').

How can I solve it?

**EDIT:**

Here an example of code that reproduces this issue:

```
        Excel.Application xlApp = null;
        Excel.Workbooks xlWorkbooks = null;

        try
        {               
            xlApp = new Excel.Application();

            xlApp.Visible = true;
            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

            xlWorkbooks = xlApp.Workbooks;

            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlWorkbooks.Open(Filename: path, ReadOnly: false);

            xlApp.Run(macro);

            xlWorkbook.RefreshAll();

            xlWorkbook.Close(SaveChanges: true);

            xlApp.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlWorkbook);
            releaseObject(xlWorkbooks);

            releaseObject(xlApp);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Erro ao executar métodos Excel");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

And here the function I implemented to release the COM objects:

```
static void releaseObject(object o)
    {
        try
        {
            if (o != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o);
        }
        catch
        {
            o = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you are closing the workbook?

Comment: I edited the original post to show you the code.

Comment: Looks good at first glance. Maybe somebody will have some insight.  Do you know for sure the macros are done running when your code is trying to quit the application?

Comment: Yes. I have in my original code an IMessageFilter implementation to handle the flow of operations and ensure that the application waits until the task has ended to start another one.